# SQL Left Join Within Timeframe Window

Tags: sql, left-join, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, dateadd

I have two datasets:

```
dataset_a
time_stamp                   user    group    value
2021-06-20 12:48:24.521         A    video        1
2021-06-15 12:50:24.521         A    video        1
2021-06-10 12:48:24.521         A    video        1    

dataset_b
time_stamp                   user    group    label
2021-06-20 09:40:24.521         A    video       BA
2021-06-19 13:30:24.521         A    video       BB  
2021-06-13 12:48:24.521         A    video       BC  
2021-06-09 12:55:24.521         A    video       BD
```

I want to create a dataset where if dataset b is within 1 day of timestamp of dataset a by timestamp, user, and group then it is a match. Has anyone done something like this before where it is something like `left join on dataset_b.timestamp between dataset_a.timestamp and date_add(dataset_a.timestamp,-1)`. I'd like to have the flexibility where in the future I can test out -7 days as well so it is easily modifiable.

Expected output below:

```
 dataset_a
time_stamp                   user    group    value    timestamp_b               label
2021-06-20 12:48:24.521         A    video      0.5    2021-06-20 09:40:24.521      BA
2021-06-20 12:48:24.521         A    video      0.5    2021-06-19 13:30:24.521      BB
2021-06-15 12:50:24.521         A    video        1    NULL                       NULL   
2021-06-10 12:48:24.521         A    video        1    2021-06-09 12:55:24.521      BD
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `JOIN` condition does not have to be only equality operator so:

```
SELECT *
FROM dataset_a
LEFT JOIN dataset_b
  ON dataset_b.user = dataset_a.user
 AND dataset_b.group = dataset_a.group
 AND dataset_b.time_stamp BETWEEN dataset_a.time_stamp - INTERVAL '1 day'
                              AND dataset_a.time_stamp ;
```

is a valid join.

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=d2507803618150efafae657efd4aad10)**

Comment: I always find it useful to supply code that can be copy/pasted into snowflake. Takes a little longer but means the SQL is validated and it's quicker for the user to get up and going :-)

Comment: @AdrianWhite This is exactly the reason I have provided live demo :) The PostgreSQL syntax could be copied almost 1:1

Comment: Awesome ... sorry didn't see/understand that. Great work.

Comment: This worked great thanks! Is there an easy way to distribute the values evenly when there are duplicates that form?

Comment: Usually I would distribute it by counting the duplicates of the match keys as a new column pre-join on each side and then divide after joining. But not sure how to do it when the match key is a range like above

Comment: or just avg(value) ... added code/pic of this working below.

Comment: @nak5120 That should be another question, but you could investigate the `QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY dataset_a.user, dataset_a.group, .... ORDER BY dataset_a.time_stamp DESC) = 1` added at the end of the query.

Answer (score 1):

A couple tweaks ... same as Lukasz just now you can copy/paste and run in snowflake :-)

```
 with dataset_a as (
select '2021-06-20 12:48:24.521'::TIMESTAMP_LTZ time_stamp, 'A' user, 
'video' groups,1 value
union all select '2021-06-15 12:50:24.521'::TIMESTAMP_LTZ time_stamp, 'A' user, 'video' groups,1 value
union all select '2021-06-10 12:48:24.521'::TIMESTAMP_LTZ time_stamp, 'A' user, 'video' groups,1 value 
) , dataset_b as( 
select '2021-06-19 13:30:24.521'::TIMESTAMP_LTZ time_stamp,'A' user,'video' groups,'BB' label  
union all select '2021-06-13 12:48:24.521'::TIMESTAMP_LTZ time_stamp,'A' user,'video' groups,'BC' label  
union all select '2021-06-09 12:55:24.521'::TIMESTAMP_LTZ time_stamp,'A' user,'video' groups,'BD' label  
union all select '2021-06-20 09:40:24.521'::TIMESTAMP_LTZ time_stamp,'A' user,'video' groups,'BA' label) 
SELECT *
FROM dataset_a
LEFT JOIN dataset_b
ON dataset_b.user = dataset_a.user
AND dataset_b.groups = dataset_a.groups
AND dataset_b.time_stamp between dataset_a.time_stamp - INTERVAL '1 day' 
and dataset_a.time_stamp ;
```

[image]

Added avg(value) to cleaning up dups ... alternatively just add avg windowed over your key  `avg(dataset_a.value) over (partition by dataset_a.time_stamp, dataset_a.user, dataset_a.groups , dataset_b.user)`

```
 with dataset_a as (
 select '2021-06-20 12:48:24.521'::TIMESTAMP_LTZ time_stamp, 'A' user, 
 'video' groups,1 value
 union all select '2021-06-15 12:50:24.521'::TIMESTAMP_LTZ time_stamp, 'A' user, 'video' groups,1 value
 union all select '2021-06-10 12:48:24.521'::TIMESTAMP_LTZ time_stamp, 'A' user, 'video' groups,1 value 
 ) , dataset_b as( 
 select '2021-06-19 13:30:24.521'::TIMESTAMP_LTZ time_stamp,'A' user,'video' groups,'BB' label  
 union all select '2021-06-13 12:48:24.521'::TIMESTAMP_LTZ time_stamp,'A' user,'video' groups,'BC' label  
 union all select '2021-06-09 12:55:24.521'::TIMESTAMP_LTZ time_stamp,'A' user,'video' groups,'BD' label  
 union all select '2021-06-20 09:40:24.521'::TIMESTAMP_LTZ time_stamp,'A' user,'video' groups,'BA' label) 
 SELECT dataset_a.time_stamp, dataset_a.user, dataset_a.groups, avg(dataset_a.value), dataset_b.time_stamp, dataset_b.user, dataset_b.groups,dataset_b.label
 FROM dataset_a
 LEFT JOIN dataset_b
 ON dataset_b.user = dataset_a.user
 AND dataset_b.groups = dataset_a.groups
 AND dataset_b.time_stamp between dataset_a.time_stamp - INTERVAL '1 day' 
 and dataset_a.time_stamp 
 group by 1,2,3,5,6,7,8
```

[image]